# Resume an ftp upload with curl

Tags: php, curl, upload, ftp, resume

i'm buidling a php script to upload larges files from a local php server to a distant ftp server with log of progress in a mysql base. Evrything work fine, but i get problem with the resume function and i can't find any clear information of the process to follow to resume an ftp upload with curl. my code bellow :

```
$fp = fopen($localfile, 'r');

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, 'curlProgressCallback'); // lof progress to base
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, 'curlAbortCallback'); // check if user request abort

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $ftp);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PORT, FTPPort);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_LIMIT, 1000);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_TIME, 20); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, FTPLog . ":" . FTPPass);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FTP_CREATE_MISSING_DIRS, true); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);

if($resume){
    $startFrom=ftpFileSize($dest); // return the actual file size on the ftp server
}else{         
    $startFrom=false;        
}

if($startFrom){ 
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_FTPAPPEND, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RESUME_FROM, $startFrom);       
    fseek($fp, $startFrom, SEEK_SET);
    $sizeToUp=filesize($localfile);//-$startFrom;        
}else{               
    $sizeToUp=filesize($localfile);
}    
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, $sizeToUp);

curl_exec($curl);
```

If someone call help me on this or redirect me on a valid example it will be very helfull and appreciate.

Tks for your feedback

Mr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i've abort my research to make resume with curl, not enought help or documentation on it,
And it's really more easy to do it with ftp_nb_put. So i f its can help someone, you can find a exemple of my final code bellow :

```
    define("FTPAdd","your serveur ftp address");                                    
    define("FTPPort",21);                                                           
    define("FTPTimeout",120);
    define("FTPLog","your login");                                                 
    define("FTPPass","your password"); 

    function ftpUp_checkForAndMakeDirs($ftpThread, $file) {
            $parts = explode("/", dirname($file));
            foreach ($parts as $curDir) {            
                if (@ftp_chdir($ftpThread, $curDir) === false) { // Attempt to change directory, suppress errors
                    ftp_mkdir($ftpThread, $curDir); //directory doesn't exist - so make it
                    ftp_chdir($ftpThread, $curDir); //go into the new directory
                }
            }
    }   
    function ftpUp_progressCallBack($uploadedData){
         global $abortRequested;
         //you can do any action you want while file upload progress, personaly, il log progress in to data base
         //and i request DB to know if user request a file transfert abort and set the  var $abortRequested to true or false
    }
    function ftpUp($src,$file,$dest,$resume){
            global $abortRequested; 

            $conn_id = ftp_connect(FTPAdd,FTPPort,FTPTimeout);
                if ($conn_id==false){
                        echo "FTP Connection problem";return false;                
                }else{
                        $login_res = ftp_login($conn_id, FTPLog, FTPPass);
                        if ($login_res){
                                $ftpThread=$conn_id;            
                        }else{
                                echo "FTP Authentification error";return false;
                        }
                }
            $fp = fopen($src, 'r');     

            ftpUp_checkForAndMakeDirs($ftpThread, $dest); //verif et creation de l'arborescence sur le serveur ftp
            ftp_set_option ($ftpThread, FTP_AUTOSEEK, TRUE); // indispensable pour pouvoir faire du resume

            if($resume){            
                $upload = ftp_nb_fput ($ftpThread, $file, $fp ,FTPUpMode, FTP_AUTORESUME);
            }else{
                $upload = ftp_nb_fput ($ftpThread, $file, $fp ,FTPUpMode);    
            }       
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            //uploading process
            while ($upload == FTP_MOREDATA) {               
                //progress of upload                
                    ftpUp_progressCallBack(ftell ($fp));                
                //continue or abort 
                if(!$abortRequested){
                    $upload = ftp_nb_continue($ftpThread);
                }else{              
                    $upload = "userAbort";
                }            
             }
             ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
             //end and result                   
             ftpUp_progressCallBack(ftell ($fp));       

             if ($upload != FTP_FINISHED) {
                 @fclose($fp);
                 @ftp_close ($ftpThread);
                 if ($abortRequested){                              
                    echo "FTP Abort by user : resume needed";
                 }else{
                    echo "FTP upload error : ".$upload." (try resume)";
                 }
             }else{
                @fclose($fp);
                @ftp_close ($ftpThread);
                echo "upload sucess";
             }

    } 


    $file="test.zip";
    $src = "FilesToUp/" . $file; 
    $destDir = "www/data/upFiles/";
    $dest = $destDir . $file;
    $abortRequested=false;

    ftpUp($src,$file,$dest,true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think cURL & PHP can do this.

Are you using Linux? If so look at aria2. It supports resumable connections and supports FTP. I am not sure if it will do exactly what you want.

Comment: Hi,I need to do it with my php server (windows server), so users can manage it (abort, progress, ... and resume) and i can log to a database. I think curl can do it because flags exist i can't just find clear documentation or help on it (CURLOPT_FTPAPPEND & CURLOPT_RESUME_FROM). Tks

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for a viable answer using CURL + PHP to resume a transfer that was broken and could not find clear, viable solution on the internet. This is an OLD question but I figured it did need a proper answer. This is the result of a day or two of research. See functions below and quick usage example.

**Connect function:**

```
function ftp_getconnect($uName, $pWord, $uHost)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$uName:$pWord");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $uHost);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $return = curl_exec($ch);
    if($return === false)
    {
        print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
        echo curl_error($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        die('Could not connect');
    }
    else
    {
        return $ch;
    }
}
```

**Disconnect function:**

```
function ftp_disconnect($ch)
{
    $return = curl_close($ch);
    if($return === false)
    {
        return "Error: Could not close connection".PHP_EOL;
    }
    else
    {
        return $return;
    }
}
```

**Function to get the remote file size (in bytes):**

```
function get_rem_file_size($ch, $rem_file)
{
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, STDIN);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $rem_file);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FTP_CREATE_MISSING_DIRS, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FTPLISTONLY, false);
    $return = curl_exec($ch);
    if($return === false)
    {
        print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
        echo curl_error($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        die('Could not connect');
    }
    else
    {
        $file_header = curl_getinfo($ch);
        return $file_header['download_content_length'];
    }
}
```

**Upload file function:**

```
function upload_file($ch,$local_file,$remote_file,$resume)
{
    echo "attempting to upload $local_file to $remote_file".PHP_EOL;
    $file = fopen($local_file, 'rb');
    if($resume)
    {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RESUME_FROM, get_rem_file_size($ch, $remote_file));
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $remote_file);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FTP_CREATE_MISSING_DIRS, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $file);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($local_file));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $return = curl_exec($ch);

    if($return === false)
    {
        fclose($file);
        return curl_error($ch).PHP_EOL;
    }
    else
    {
        fclose($file);
        echo $local_file.' uploaded'.PHP_EOL;
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Quick usage example:**

```
$ftp = ftp_getconnect($uName, $pWord, 'ftp://'.$uHost);

$rem_file = 'ftp://'.$uHost.'/path/to/remote/file.ext';
$loc_file = 'path/to/local/file.ext';
$resume = 'true';
$success = upload_file($ftp, $loc_file, $rem_file, $resume);
if($success !== true)
{
    //failure
    echo $success;
    curl_close($ch);
}
print_r(ftp_disconnect($ftp));
```

Quick note, if there is a large set of files, you can loop through them and `upload_file` without connecting/disconnecting each time.